# SQL Where Clauuse Date - Not A Valid Month Error

Tags: sql, database, oracle, date, where-clause

I'm trying to run this sql query in SQL Developer (Using Oracle Database). Basically I want to select all the columns given where A.APPT_DATE is at least 2 months old but I keep on getting a 'not a valid month error' - highlighted this bit in bold. If I take this where clause out, it works fine.

```
SELECT D.DOC_ID AS "Doctor ID", D.STATUS, A.APPT_DATE, COUNT(DISTINCT A.APPT_ID) AS "Number of appointments", DI.CASE, P.PET_ID AS "Pet ID", P.PET_NAME AS "Pet Name"
FROM VET_DOCTOR D
JOIN 
APPOINTMENT A ON (D.DOC_ID=A.DOC_ID) WHERE A.APPT_DATE <= DATE '10-January-2016'
JOIN 
DIAGNOSIS DI ON (A.APPT_ID=DI.APPT_ID) 
JOIN
PET P ON (A.PET_ID=P.PET_ID) WHERE DI.CASE IN('Socialisation','Dental') 
GROUP BY D.DOC_ID, D.STATUS, A.APPT_DATE, A.APPT_ID, DI.CASE, P.PET_ID, P.PET_NAME;
```

Comment: Try the date as '10 January 2016' (without the -)

Comment: which database?

Comment: @kevchadders I tried and got the following error: Cause:    Literals in the input must be the same length as literals in
           the format string (with the exception of leading whitespace).  If the
           "FX" modifier has been toggled on, the literal must match exactly,
           with no extra whitespace.

Comment: I assume those ** in your code are in there by error. ps. From your error message its Oracle as your DB

Comment: @BhaveshGhodasara Oracle, using SQL Developer

Comment: @kevchadders Yes sorry I tried to bold the bits I wanted to highlight. Edited the code now.

Comment: First check the date format in your Table and try something like `WHERE A.APPT_DATE <='10-JAN-2016'.

Comment: If the date format in your table is different then you should use a different format.

Comment: Try this as well it might work for you `WHERE A.APPT_DATE <= TO_DATE('10/JAN/2016','dd/mon/yyyy') `

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but I guess the date format is like that `DD-Mon-YYYY`. So you would need to do it like that: `'10-JAN-2016'`

Let me know if that helped.

Comment: Date format is DD-MM-YYYY and dates are input as '01-January-1999' For example. I just tried your suggestion but it still gives me the 'Not a valid month' error. Thanks

Comment: Well according to your Date Format `DD-MM-YYYY` you should use `'10-01-2016'` right?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your dates as stored under the correct data type `DATE`

can you try the YYYY-MM-DD format i'm hoping it will work using [Datetime Literals](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements003.htm#BABGIGCJ)

```
<= DATE '2016-01-10'
```

Comment: Thanks I tried your suggestion but I receive the following error:   SQL command not properly ended"

Comment: Can you simplify the query for now in case the error is in another part of the SQL.  So try something like: SELECT * FROM APPOINTMENT WHERE APPT_DATE <= DATE '2016-01-10'

Comment: or use another date format suggestion. this will help you focus in on the date issue

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 WHERE A.APPT_DATE <= TO_DATE('10/JAN/2016','dd/mon/yyyy')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
to_DATE('10-01-2016','DD-MM-YYYY')
```

so you are indipendent from language

Answer (score 0):

2 things:
1. If you want to do the standard way, the date should be input as 'DD-Mon-YYYY', example, '01-Jan-2016'.

Hence your query would be:

```
    SELECT D.DOC_ID AS "Doctor ID", D.STATUS, A.APPT_DATE, COUNT(DISTINCT A.APPT_ID) AS "Number of appointments", DI.CASE, P.PET_ID AS "Pet ID", P.PET_NAME AS "Pet Name"
    FROM VET_DOCTOR D
    JOIN 
    APPOINTMENT A ON (D.DOC_ID=A.DOC_ID) WHERE A.APPT_DATE <= '10-Jan-2016'
    JOIN 
    DIAGNOSIS DI ON (A.APPT_ID=DI.APPT_ID) 
    JOIN
    PET P ON (A.PET_ID=P.PET_ID) WHERE DI.CASE IN('Socialisation','Dental') 
    GROUP BY D.DOC_ID, D.STATUS, A.APPT_DATE, A.APPT_ID, DI.CASE, P.PET_ID, P.PET_NAME;
```

If this gives error, try this:

Run following query:

```
    ALTER SESSION SET nls_date_format = 'DD-Mon-YYYY';
```

This would force the use of standard format of date input.

2. If you want it to be input as full month only, then:

   ```
   ALTER SESSION SET nls_date_format = 'DD-Month-YYYY';
   ```

Then run your query:

```
    SELECT D.DOC_ID AS "Doctor ID", D.STATUS, A.APPT_DATE, COUNT(DISTINCT A.APPT_ID) AS "Number of appointments", DI.CASE, P.PET_ID AS "Pet ID", P.PET_NAME AS "Pet Name"
    FROM VET_DOCTOR D
    JOIN 
    APPOINTMENT A ON (D.DOC_ID=A.DOC_ID) WHERE A.APPT_DATE <= '10-January-2016'
    JOIN 
    DIAGNOSIS DI ON (A.APPT_ID=DI.APPT_ID) 
    JOIN
    PET P ON (A.PET_ID=P.PET_ID) WHERE DI.CASE IN('Socialisation','Dental') 
    GROUP BY D.DOC_ID, D.STATUS, A.APPT_DATE, A.APPT_ID, DI.CASE, P.PET_ID, P.PET_NAME;
```

Also in your original query I see a DATE, were you trying to cast your date '10-Jan-2016' to a date for comparison? in that case you need it to be like TO_DATE('your date here', 'format string').
Why I ask this is because, take a look at the two queries below, first throws error(same as what you are getting), and second does not:

```
    SELECT sysdate FROM dual WHERE sysdate >= DATE '10-January-2016';
    SELECT sysdate FROM dual WHERE sysdate >= '10-January-2016';
```

Comment: Refer https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements004.htm#CDEHIFJA for a full list of date formats.

Comment: Do not rely on `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` to give a consistent date format - it is a session variable and can be different for every user and each user can change it to whatever format they want in their session. If you want a specific date format mask then [specify it (with the NLS settings) in the `TO_DATE`function](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/oracle/2087/dates/6846/generating-dates-with-no-time-component#t=201612051401455871023).

Comment: Agreed to that. Just wanted the user to check to come down to the actual issue. Though I think the issue is the use of word date before they are entering the actual date, refer to my last lines in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of the answers here quite rightly point out that you need to use the TO_DATE function to convert your string into a date, and that you must state the format.  However your original post says you want to extract entities that are 'at least two months old'.  For this I would use :

```
WHERE A.APPT_DATE <= ADD_MONTHS(sysdate,-2)
```

Then you don't need to re-write your query tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

The `WHERE` clause cannot be in the middle of the `JOIN` clauses:

```
SELECT D.DOC_ID AS "Doctor ID",
       D.STATUS,
       A.APPT_DATE,
       COUNT(DISTINCT A.APPT_ID) AS "Number of appointments",
       DI.CASE,
       P.PET_ID AS "Pet ID",
       P.PET_NAME AS "Pet Name"
FROM   VET_DOCTOR D
       JOIN APPOINTMENT A ON (D.DOC_ID=A.DOC_ID)
       JOIN DIAGNOSIS DI ON (A.APPT_ID=DI.APPT_ID) 
       JOIN PET P ON (A.PET_ID=P.PET_ID)
WHERE  DI.CASE IN('Socialisation','Dental') 
AND    A.APPT_DATE <= DATE '2016-01-10'
GROUP BY D.DOC_ID, D.STATUS, A.APPT_DATE, A.APPT_ID, DI.CASE, P.PET_ID, P.PET_NAME;
```

Also, if you are going to use date literals then you need to use the format `DATE 'YYYY-MM-DD'` so `DATE '2016-01-10'`.

However, as [Christian Palmer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40973153/1509264) mentioned, if you want entries that are at least two months old then you can use:

```
AND A.APPT_DATE <= ADD_MONTHS( SYSDATE, -2 );
```

Answer (score 0):

This has worked for me:

```
cast (RN_EXECUTION_date as Date) >= '31-MAR-2018'
```

`RN_EXECUTION_Date` was in Date Timestamp format. Using the `cast` function, converted it to Date format (DD-MON-YEAR)